# The New York Knicks Bobblehead in 1920

Tags: basketball, history, collectibles

One of the first bobbleheads was supposedly made in 1920 by the New York Knicks. However, the New York Knicks came into existence in 1946. This obviously presents a discrepancy. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: You are right that the Knicks began in 1946. What is your source that talks about the early Knicks bobble head?

Comment: Nicks are a basketball team, so I changed your baseball tag to a basketball tag!

Comment: If you're interested, I received an inconclusive but helpful email from the folks at the National Bobblehead Hall of Fame, so it's possible this will eventually have a good answer!

Answer (score 4):

I don't see anything more specific than Ben Miller's comments on bobbleheads.

However, I would note that the [Original Celtics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Celtics) were active in New York (not Boston) in the 1920s, and they were a very showman-like - even circus-like - team; basically a slightly more serious version of the Harlem Globetrotters, with a similar record (193-11-1).  It seems likely they would have thought of something like this.

There was also the Harlem Rens in this period, who were commonly the opponents of the Celtics.

---

Follow up:  I emailed the folks at the [National Bobblehead Hall of Fame](https://www.bobbleheadhall.com/), and they replied with (in part):

> We did add a note to our site regarding this bobblehead and the fact
>   we are investigating further. It's odd that so many sites have listed
>   this information. We have spent a good amount of time looking into
>   this and haven't been able to find anything conclusive yet. I will
>   appeal to the folks on the Bobblehead Addicts page and some sports
>   historians in the New York area to get to the bottom of this. I will
>   surely let you know what we find out!

Answer (score 2):

This is turning out to be a very interesting question.  Doing some research, I have found a few different sources claiming that sports bobbleheads got their start in the 1920s with the New York Knicks:

- Bobbleheads.com: [History of Bobbleheads](http://www.bobbleheads.com/history-of-bobbleheads.html)
- Historyofdolls.com: [History of Bobblehead](http://www.historyofdolls.com/history-of-famous-dolls/history-of-bobblehead/)
- National Bobblehead Hall of Fame and Museum: [History of Bobbles](http://www.bobbleheadhall.com/history/)

These articles, unfortunately, provide no sources.  They are not a copy-and-pastes of each other.  This "fact" was even picked up by [a recent article in the Tampa Bay Tribune](http://tbo.com/sports/blogs/sports-bookie/heres-a-nod-toward-a-national-bobblehead-museum-20141124/).

However, this cannot actually be true, since the New York Knicks did not begin until 1946.  I think this is just a matter of some article somewhere putting out this "fact" and everyone else just assuming it is true.  But I haven't been able to determine what the original source is.

Comment: Any chance they were talking about the early baseball team, the New York Knickerbockers? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Knickerbockers

Comment: @Leatherwing Good thought, but I don't think the New York Knickerbockers baseball team survived into the 1920s.  See [this article about the history of the team](http://www.baseballchronology.com/baseball/leagues/NABBP/Clubs/New-York-Knickerbockers.asp).